# lapply needs boolean after if-statement condition

Tags: r, function, if-statement, lapply

I'm new to R. I wrote a function that applies to numbers and want to apply it to a numeric of length 400. It goes

```
 EGIDS.to.IUCN <- function(x){
   if(x==10){return(NA)} # 10 (Extinct)
   if(x==9){return(NA)} # 9 (Dormant)
   if(x==8.5){return(4)} # 8.5 (Nearly Extinct) → 4 (Critically endangered) 
   # 10 more similar lines here (no more NAs)
   else{stop}
 }
```

I tried using lapply but then I get

```
> austroIUCN <- lapply(austroEGIDS, EGIDS.to.IUCN)
Error in if (x == 10) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Where austroEGIDS is a list of 400 numbers from 0 to 10. I'm totally lost here. Why does it expect a boolean after closing the if condition?

Comment: Does `austroEGIDS` contain missing values (`NA`)?

Comment: what is the `stop` statement supposed to do?  Do you want an `NA` if not meeting one of the conditions?  Because if you remove the `stop` it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more efficient if you use a numeric vector and work with vectorized statements:

```
austroIUCN <- unlist(austroEGIDS)
austroIUCN[austroIUCN==10 | austroIUCN==9] <- NA
austroIUCN[austroIUCN==8.5] <- 4
...
```

Each statements sets all entries with the given level.

Comment: It worked, but I had to invert the row order since originally, further in my list at `austroIUCN[austroIUCN==4] <- 0.25`, the `8.5` value converted into `4` at `austroIUCN[austroIUCN==8.5] <- 4` would get converted into `0.25`.

Answer (score 1):

Without the `stop` this should work,

```
EGIDS.to.IUCN <- function(x) {
    if (is.na(x)){ NA } else
        if (x == 10) { NA } else
            if (x == 9) { NA } else
                if(x == 8.5) { 4 } else
                    NA
}
```

or, more readable and faster,

```
EGIDS.to.IUCN <- function(x){
    switch (x, 'NA'=NA, '10'=NA, '9'=NA, '8.5'=4, NA)
}

austroEGIDS <- sample(seq(1, 10, .5), 400, replace = TRUE)
austroIUCN <- sapply(austroEGIDS, EGIDS.to.IUCN)
table(unlist(austroIUCN), useNA = "ifany")

austroIUCN
   4 <NA> 
  23  377
```

Or if you want it to stop and throw an error if not a match,

```
EGIDS.to.IUCN <- function(x){
    switch (x, 'NA'=NA, '10'=NA, '9'=NA, '8.5'=4, stop("Not a match!"))
}
```

Comment: When I use your function with your sample data, it works. However, when I use your function with my data it doesn't - there are a few NAs in my list, but nothing else out of the ordinary. Further, when I use my old function (less the stop) with your sample data, I get the same error.

Comment: It worked but I used Karsten's code to get it into a numeric, since I couldn't coerce the list into one.